# Set Style of ComboBoxItem = null, but programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have in my XAML the following lines as Window.Resources:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="pics/greenbutton.png" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Style>
```

In my Window are several ComboBoxes where this is good. But I have one, where it is disturbing, so I wanted to set the style to null. I already put a `Style="{x:Null}"` inside the XAML-ComboBox. That gives the ComboBox itself a good view, but not the open Box (i.e. the ComboBoxItems). I use a DataBinding inside the Code-Behind, so how can I delete the window-style for the ComboBoxItems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to `ComboBox` resources empty style with target type `ComboBoxItem`.

You can do this in the XAML like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" ...>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
 ...
</ComboBox>
```

Or you can do this in the code-behind using following code:

```
myComboBox.Resources.Add(typeof(ComboBoxItem), new Style(typeof(ComboBoxItem)));
```